# log4j warning when building wso2 kernel

Tags: log4j, wso2

I'm getting bellow log4j warning when i'm building any wso2 products and kernel.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

how do i configure it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

That log4j warning is coming as there are no log4j appenders configured for that particular logger.

You need to [configure log4j properly to avoid that warning](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig).

I have seen that warning when building stubs in WSO2 code. I haven't seen that for `org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder`

Please send a mail to [WSO2 dev@ mailing list](http://wso2.com/mail/) with all details such as which branch etc.